# Passing a parameter to onclick listener on a button in a listview row

Tags: android, listview, button

I just started android and I'm running into some problems.
I have created a `ListView` that is populated from a database.
Each row has a button to delete the item from the list and the database.

I am able to hook up an event listener to the button but I have not been able to determine the matching database record to be deleted.

My class is shown below

```
public class FeedArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Feed> implements OnClickListener
{
    private ARssEReaderDBAdapter dba;
    private String TAG = "FeedArrayAdapter";

    public FeedArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Feed> items)          {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
    Log.w(TAG, "List");


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.w(TAG, "getView");
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.feedlistrow, null);
    }
    Feed feed = getItem(position);
    if (feed != null) {
        TextView title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        if (title != null) {
            title.setText(feed.getTitle());
        }
        Button btnDelete = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(this); //btnDeleteFeedListener
    }
    return v;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.w(TAG, "something got clicked: ");
}
```

So how can I pass the database record ID to the handler so I can use the database adapter to delete it?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You should store the ID of the record in the Tag, call `setTag()` on your view, and to read in onclick call `getTag()`

Answer (score 22):

Create a inner class that implements OnClickListener and then pass the position variable in the constructor.

```
 private Class MyClickListener implements OnClickListener {

    private int position;

    public MyClickListener(int position) {
       this.position = position;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
       System.out.println("position " + getPosition() + " clicked.");
    }

    public int getPosition() {
      return position;
    }

 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, the Tag options seemed to be the easiest to implement and does all I want it to do :)

Thanks again

Comment: I like this answer because my setTag() was already being used for something else.

Comment: This worked out great as I needed to pass more than one value to a click listener! Thanks

Comment: setTag(int key, Object tag) can be used to pass more than one value.